# How do you find the time to answer questions on SO?

Tags: discussion

I've been thinking about this many times, that as a person who is spending most of his days coding and learning programming, I should give back of what I learn here and answer questions of other programmers, but due to the lack of time (or maybe discipline), I wasn't successful at this at all. yet I see a lot of professional programmers with astronomically high reputations, people who give accurate responses to though questions at no time.

what is your advice for becoming a useful member of this community?

Comment: For me personally, I find that I am most effective at answering questions on Stack Overflow *when I am currently doing work in the technology I am answering questions in.*  Answering questions becomes very efficient, because you already know the answers to the questions without having to do a lot of research.

Comment: related: [Top users on stackoverflow: slackers or superstars?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12468/top-users-on-stackoverflow-slackers-or-superstars)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/what-advice-would-you-give-beginners-joining-a-stack-exchange-site http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57924/how-much-time-is-too-much-to-spend-answering-a-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142911/having-a-bad-start-is-that-normal http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81616/how-should-users-start-earning-reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have thousands of new questions every day on Stack Overflow. Here is what I do:

[I watch the tags that I am familar with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+or+sql+or+sql-server+or+oracle?sort=newest&pageSize=30) / program with. When you watch tags you get live updates on new questions.

If you watch popular tags then you have hundreds of questions you could possibly answer every day. Pick two or three and write an answer to it and you will do just fine.